# Adjusting the position of page number in a book/note

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

I have written up a note/book (actually my thesis) with parts in it, and ran into the following problem:

To make the note divide into parts, I used `\part` command, e.g. `\part{This is part I}`, and this produced a separate page where it centers the text `part I`, and then write below (still centering) `This is part I` (I typed something different that 'This is part I', however that is irrelevant), and that's all what is on the page. So far this is fine, but while numbering the page, it writes the page number at the central bottom, instead of the top right, where it writes all the other page numbers, different from the 'parting page numbers'. But my university want **all** the pages to be numbered in the same way, and they want all the numbers to appear at the top right of the page.

Could you please suggest me how to make all the page numbers appear at the top right of the page, specially, the numbers for those 'parting pages'?

Comment: You should add an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us were your problem is.  I guess you have problems with the usage of package `fancyhdr` or `scrpage2` ...

Comment: I actually didn't use any of those packages, but only used documentclass \ruthesis, which is a standard thesis-style document class. Every page number is fine, except, when I use the command \part, it changes the position of the age numbering and writes the number below on the center bottom of the page. I just want that number to appear at the top right, just like other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Because I do not know your class I give you an MWE for class `book` with package `fancyhdr`.
With `fancyhdr` you can controll your header and footer of your document. Use `texdoc fancyhdr`for more informations or search this site for tag `fancyhdr`.

I do not know if this work with class `ruthesis`. Please try it by your own.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}%fancy plain   we redefine style plain
\fancyhf{}                         % delete all fields
\cfoot{}                           % no pagenumer in foot
\fancyhead[RO,EL]{\thepage}        % page numer in header, right+left side
\fancyhead[ER]{\chaptermark}       % chaptertitle left
\fancyhead[OL]{\sectionmark}       % sectiontitle right
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule


\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{plain}% define style footer/header

\part{One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Text Text Text.
\section{Section One}
Text Text Text.
\clearpage
Text Text Text.

\part{two}
\chapter{Chapter two}
Text Text Text

\end{document}
```